# Python Open File - If Else Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, text, with-statement

I am confused about the output of my code.

This is my file:

```
201707001 Jenson_ 
201707002 Richard 
201707003 Jean
```

This is my code:

```
def studentInfo (userInput):  # storing student info
    # read the students file
    with open('C:\\Users\\jaspe\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\Student.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            stdId, stdName = line.strip().split(" ", 1)
            # check if the student exist
            if userInput == stdId:
                print("Student found!")
                print("Student ID: " + stdId + "\nStudent Name: " + stdName)
            else:
                print("The student does not exist")


studentFinder = input("Please enter id: ")
studentInfo(studentFinder)
```

This is my output of the code

```
Please enter id: 201707001
Student found!
Student ID: 201707001
Student Name: Jenson
The student does not exist
The student does not exist
```

How do I fix my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `else` statement comes too soon. It will output "found" when found, and on the next line it will output "not found"!

You cannot know that you didn't find the student until end of file is reached.

Let me propose a solution using `else` counterpart for `for`:

```
    for line in f:
        stdId, stdName = line.strip().split(" ", 1)
        # check if the student exist
        if userInput == stdId:
            print("Student found!")
            print("Student ID: " + stdId + "\nStudent Name: " + stdName)
            break
    else:
        print("The student does not exist")
```

now if student is found, call `break`. If `break` isn't called, `else` of the `for` loop is entered. Nice python feature, not well-known

(doesn't work if you want to match several times).

Note that on the long run, you may want to store your file contents in a dictionary so lookup will be faster for multiple searches:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\jaspe\\Desktop\\PADS Assignment\\Student.txt') as f:
    d = dict(zip(line.split(" ",1) for line in f)
```

now `d` is your id => name dictionary, using fast lookup when you have a lot of queries to perform (file is just read once, and dictionary uses hash for fast search)

Comment: That's interesting. I've never seen an `else` used like that before. Is this considered "best practice?"

Comment: @CoryMadden - it is part of the language, if it helps solve a problem and is *readable*, use it.

Comment: @wwii and I just might. I'm really just wondering if there's any reason not to use it. There are plenty of things that are part of the language that are considered "bad" to use, such as using `eval`. Of course everything has it's use case, but does this have any pitfalls one should be aware of when using it?

Comment: this is a very interesting language . thank you for the answer

Comment: @CoryMadden it avoids the use of a flag. `eval` is bad because it's unsafe (code injection). Not the case here. Thanks for your upvotes :)